# How to get all fields which are present in display form?

Tags: web-services, display-form

I want to list down all the fields which are present in `SPList` in the Display form.

Also I want to know the display order for the fields.

How can I get this information?

In further detail... 
I have write the custom services for my mobile application with the server side CSOM object.
I wanted to show the List item with the details as same as the SharePoint display form shows.

I am able to get the all fields from the list but wanted show the fields which actual present in display form is same order.

For that how can i get the fields

Comment: Hi! Your question will get more attention if you tag it with the SharePoint version in question (2010, 2013 etc). :)

Comment: @RobertLindgren - weren't we supposed to use the version tags only when the question is specific to a SharePoint version? don't feel it is the case.

Comment: I have no idea if the question is targeted to a version or not, but when it comes to webservices, and CSOM, these API:s differ quite a lot between the different versions (especially what can be done, and what can't). :)

Answer (score 1):

You must use SPFieldLink class to get the order of fields in content type see the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlink.aspx).
To get all fields from Display form you need get all fields from content type that not hidden.

```
var contentTypeCollection;
  var contentType;
  var fieldLinks;

  function getFieldLinks() {
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
  var web = clientContext.get_web();
  this.contentTypeCollection = web.get_contentTypes();
  this.contentType = contentTypeCollection.getById("0x01001EE585131CF22F448BB03959CA66EB11");
  this.fieldLinks = this.contentType.get_fieldLinks();
  clientContext.load(this.fieldLinks);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
  }
  }

  function onQuerySucceeded() {
  var fieldLink = "Field Links :\n ";
  var fieldLinksEnumerator = this.fieldLinks.getEnumerator();
  while (fieldLinksEnumerator.moveNext()) {
  var link = fieldLinksEnumerator.get_current();
  fieldLink += link.get_name() + '\n';
  }
  alert(fieldLink);
  }
```

Comment: Can you please let me know any CSOM example for the same....

Comment: In further detail... 
I have write the custome services for my mobile application with the serverside CSOM object.
I wanted to show the List item with the details as same as the sharepoint display form shows.

I am able to get the all fields from the list but wanted show the fields which actual presnt in diplay form is same order.

For that how can i get the fields

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell to get a list of fields and show if they are hidden

Code below loops through the contenttypes in a list and show if the field is shown in a display form. The order of the FieldLinks collections is the display order in the forms.

```
$url = "<url of site here>
$listName = "<name of the list here>
$web = Get-SPWeb $url
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList($listName)
$list.ContentTypes | % { $_.FieldLinks } | select Name, Hidden
```