# What SharePoint code determines the order of the fields in the Edit form?

Tags: 2013, development, jsom

Where can I find the code in SharePoint that determines the order of and what fields are in the Edit form? I have looked at the EditForm.aspx page and it doesn't look like this is determined there. If possible I would like to display a list generated with JSOM based off the order the fields appear in on the edit page.

**Edit** Could using the RenderListForm method with the REST API be a solution? It looks promising but I can't find much documentation.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by categories.  Can you elaborate?  DO you mean the order of fields?  That's determined by the content type of the list.

Comment: Yes I meant fields.  So how would I access the code the content type is using to set the order of the fields? could I use a CAML query?

Comment: You just want to change the order of the column in edit form right??

Comment: No, I want to have another list view where the order of the columns changes if the order of the fields in the Edit column is changed.

Comment: If you retrieve a list of fields and iterate over it, they should be in the same order as they are in the content type.

Comment: What method of retrieving the list of fields are you thinking of?  Because I have mainly used JSOM and based on my understanding of that the  fields have to be called individually so the order is determined by the order they are called in the code.

Comment: If you want to change the order of fields in the edit form, simply go to the list settings.  You may need to enable content types for the list first under Advanced settings. If you want to change the order of fields in a view, simply modify the view.  The two are separate and should not impact each other.

Comment: I am aware of that. But I want to display the fields an a different page but have the order change automatically along with automatically adding any new fields that are created. I don't know how to do this since when an item is retrieved by JSOM or REST each field you want displayed has to be specified (ie oListItem.get_item('Title')).

Comment: You could potentially use JSOM to retrieve the content type from the list, and see what order the fieldrefs are in the content type definition.

Comment: @DylanCristy How do you retrieve the order of the fieldrefs in the content type definition? I have been able to see how to look up the content type but I don't see much on how to extract further information from it.

Comment: Here is the MSDN documentation on the JS `SP.ContentType` object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245579.aspx As you can see, there is a property called `fieldLinks` that will give you a `SP.FieldLinkCollection` object.  You can get that by doing `var fieldLinks = myContentType.get_fieldLinks();`.  From there you might be able to enumerate through them, or somehow get the length of the collection and use `fieldLinks.itemAt(idx)` to get each field link by its index.

Comment: Cool I was able to get all the fields in the content type. This post was also very helpful http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83560/how-to-get-all-fields-which-are-present-in-display-form I think enumerating through them should let me do what I want to do.

Comment: @DylanCristy Is there a way to get the display names of the fields in the content type along with the internal name using get_fieldLinks? I would like to use both.

Comment: I don't think you can get the display names from the `SP.FieldLink` objects directly, but once you have those, you can get the `SP.Field` objects from the list using either the ID or the internal name from the field link.  Then you can get the display name from the actual `SP.Field` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the fields in the new/edit forms is determined by the order of the field links in the content type definition for the content type of the list.

Here is the [MSDN documentation on the JS `SP.ContentType` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245579.aspx).

You can use JSOM to get the content type from the list, and it will have a property called `fieldLinks` that will give you a `SP.FieldLinkCollection` object. You can get that by doing

`var fieldLinks = myContentType.get_fieldLinks();`

From there you might be able to enumerate through them, or somehow get the length of the collection and use `fieldLinks.itemAt(idx)` to get each field link by its index.

If you need the display names of the fields, you will not be able to get them directly from the `fieldLink` objects, but using the ID or internal name provided by the `fieldLink` objects, you can get the actual `SP.Field` objects from the list and access their display names that way.